# C# sort an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Quick question since other methods I tried didn't work.

I have the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Lines> Colors { get; set; }

Colors = new ObservableCollection<Lines>();

_lines.ItemsSource = Colors;
```

Then I use a loop to add colors to my collection. I use a button to add a new color with a `lineId`.

These colors have a `lineID` (`int`) which results in the following:

```
Blue with lineId = 1.
Red with lineId = 2.
Green with lineId = 4.
Yellow with lineId = 3.
```

With my code it can happen that they are in the wrong order. Instead of having Yellow as my last color, I want it to be Red. So I have to sort my list.

But here is my problem, I tried the following three options but they didn't work:

```
_lines.ItemsSource = Colors.OrderBy(j => j.lineId) ;

Colors = new ObservableCollection<Lines>(Colors.OrderBy(j => j .lineId));

foreach (var item in Colors.OrderBy(j => j.lineId))
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: How would be "Red" your last item by _any_ sorting? Neither given lineIds nor the name can do that for you.

Comment: `OrderBy` should work - have you looked at it in the debugger to verify?

Comment: @Jason How? Red would _not_ be the last item, or am I missing something? ( I am referring to this line in question: _"Instead of having yellow as my last color, **I want it to be red**."_ )

Comment: If you have a `Color` structure, you could sort by the color components: `Colors.OrderBy(j => j.color.R).ThenByDescending(j => j.color.G).ThenByDescending(j => j.color.B)`. However, we do not know how your colors are stored and we do not know what the sort criterion is. How would the other colors be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by sort by **Id**.

Below is the code in page.cs:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Lines> Colors { get; set; }

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Colors = new ObservableCollection<Lines>();
        Colors.Add(new Lines() { Id = 1, Color = "blue" });
        Colors.Add(new Lines() { Id = 2, Color = "red" });
        Colors.Add(new Lines() { Id = 4, Color = "green" });
        Colors.Add(new Lines() { Id = 3, Color = "yellow" });

        List<Lines> list = Colors.ToList();//convert to list
        list.Sort((l, r) => l.Id.CompareTo(r.Id));//sort by list.Id
        Colors = new ObservableCollection<Lines>(list);//revert back to observablecollection
        mytest.ItemsSource = Colors;//binding to xaml

    }
```

code in **xaml**:

```
    <ListView x:Name="mytest">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Color}"></Label>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This actually breaks the ObservableCollection connection, so if the Collection is updated in the background the changes won't be reflected in the UI.